# How to display url from DB into php page?

Tags: php, database, url, hyperlink

I would like to know how to insert two data from sql as hyperlink. here is my code:

```
$HTML .= "<tr><td>{$result['first_name']}</td><td>{$result['last_name']}</td></tr>";
```

As you can see, there are two data, first_name and last_name, I'm gonna show it like this:

```
<a href="last_name">first_name</a>
```

Please guide me like my above code. Thank you. 
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Try this..expecting last_name have url value

```
  $HTML .= "<tr><td><a href=".$result['last_name'].">".$result['first_name']."</a></td></tr>";
```

Comment: Thanks buddy done. It's correct. Thank you. [SOLVED]

Answer (score 0):

Hey you have to display last_name in anchor tag and first name variable in display or in link

```
$HTML .= "<a href='{$result['last_name']}'>{$result['first_name']}</a>";
```